# Function __base64Encode not works with Random Variable

Tags: jmeter

Problem with usage **__base64Encode** function to encode **Random Variable**.
I use **Random Variable** to generate unique email for user. (in each iteration  of test scenario)

I want to use :
${__base64Encode(${randomvar})} which generate encoded ${randomvar}

Real example user defined variable 'babretr' defined below:
babretr=${__base64Encode(${randomMail}${timeStamp}@jmeter.soi:Kazek2017@)}

after base64 **encode** looks:

```
babretr=JHtyYW5kb21NYWlsfTIwMTcwNTE5MDg0MTI0NDcyWkBqbWV0ZXIuc29pOkthemVrMjAxN0A=
```

after base64 **decode** looks:

```
${randomMail}20170519084124472Z@jmeter.soi:Kazek2017@
```

Jmeter Random Variable ${randomMail} is not encoded.
With different variables problem does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add Beanshell PreProcessor on your sampler and put something like:

```
import java.util.Base64;    
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;

String sufix = "@jmeter.soi:Kazek2017@";
String address = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(new String(
                RandomStringUtils.random(10) + vars.get("timeStamp") + sufix).getBytes());

vars.put("encodedAddress", address);
```

After that, just use `${encodedAddress}` in your sampler.